# Linking to an anchor tag on another page

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some sections with buttons that link to specific divs on another page. They are working fine using

```
<a id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" href="http://example.com/services.html#corporate" role="button">More</a>
```

which link to a div on another page with the id of "corporate" and so on.

The issue is that when the page opens, just before it focuses on the anchor tag, it sort of flashes the main header before focusing on the div. Is there anyway to avoid this? Once you follow the links once and go back again its fine so it seems like its just a matter of it loading and showing that first before focusing on the div. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: There's no way to avoid that, the page loads before it gets the url hash and scrolls

Comment: It happens because the browser loads the whole page before jumping to the div. There is now way to avoid it except maybe building your own browser.

Comment: @litelite "Build your own browser" you say? That seems like a bit of an undertaking. o.O

Comment: @FrankerZ I know, i said that to add a pinch of humour.

Comment: Ok I thought as much, the client doesnt want a scroll down to div so just wondered was there another way around it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Not really. The issue is that the page isn't loaded entirely at the very instant you navigate to it, and as such the `#corporate` anchor doesn't exist for a brief moment. As a result you get flashed the top of the page first, then navigated to the appropriate anchor once it's available.

Comment: You can try adding a small delay and then add a smooth scroll to the div you want.

Comment: you could also make the opacity of the entire page fade in when you get addressed

Comment: @T.Okahara that would be possible only if he owned the page he has linked. If he were attempting to send users to a particular location on a foreign page, there'd be no way to introduce a delay.

Comment: Thanks for that, ya I thought of that but the client doesnt want a scroll down to it just wants to land directly on the anchor so just wondering was there another way around it. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery to scroll down to the ID. At least then it is a smooth process. That way, you also give the user an idea of where on the page the ID is located, so they don't get confused as to where they have navigated to.

```
var j = (document.URL.substring(document.URL.lastIndexOf("\/")+1));
var hash = j.substring(j.lastIndexOf("#"))
if(j.lastIndexOf("#")!=-1) 
{
var j = j.substring(0,j.lastIndexOf("#"))
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash+'').offset().top
                     }, 1000);
});
```

I have grabbed this code from a site I use this on, so sorry if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Hope it works. Not exactly what you're after, but nice all the same.